# How are '//' and '/*...*/' comment lines taken as?

Tags: c, comments

I was making a C program that removes comments from a program...
so i was wondering if `'//'`, `'/*'` and `'*\'` taken as 1 character, (like `\t`, `\n` `\b`) or are they taken as 2 characters ( literally, i.e `/(1)/(2)` )
Thanks :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  There are already several programs for removing comments from C code.

Comment: You will likely find that correct lexical analysis of a C program is a daunting task.  [Try starting here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) or [Annex A of the C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean to ask what happens if you write `'//'`, with the quotes, that is, a two-character *character constant*, in your C program that is supposed to remove comments?

Comment: @devnull: wheels are routinely reinvented on SO as learning exercises.  If the objective is to produce production-quality programs, then you're probably correct — though I've got a fair number of reinvented wheels in my private tool chest, some of which were invented before someone else reinvented them, and some of which were for my edification, but I like them because they're mine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The comment was particularly because of the fact that the problem in question isn't exactly trivial (especially if it were to *work correctly*).

Comment: Should the interpreter be able to handle all evil special cases of C? Trigraphs and string literals? `"\??//*"` for example :)   (it's the code for printing `\/*` in a very obfuscated manner)

Comment: @devnull, trust me, I'm not that keen to do this stuff too, but if everyone said that, we'd never have Linux, OS X, etc...
Also, this is an exercise from The C Programming Language, I don't want to miss a single one :)

Comment: @lundin, I just want to build the base here, and I can then build up from there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-character character constants such as `'//'` are valid but have implementation-defined values.

Note that stripping C comments is hard.  This is part of the torture test I use on my C comment stripper:

```
"And escaped double quotes at the end of a string\""

aa '\\
n' OK
aa "\""
aa "\
\n"

This is followed by C++/C99 comment number 1.
// C++/C99 comment with \
continuation character \
on three source lines (this should not be seen with the -C flag)
The C++/C99 comment number 1 has finished.

This is followed by C++/C99 comment number 2.
/\
/\
C++/C99 comment (this should not be seen with the -C flag)
The C++/C99 comment number 2 has finished.

This is followed by regular C comment number 1.
/\
*\
Regular
comment
*\
/
The regular C comment number 1 has finished.

/\
\/ This is not a C++/C99 comment!

This is followed by C++/C99 comment number 3.
/\
\
\
/ But this is a C++/C99 comment!
The C++/C99 comment number 3 has finished.
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there were so many ways... but I was wondering if I could just prepare a base ( i.e, '//','/*' and '*\'.
I'll work my way from up there...
So are these symbols that denote comments taken as 1 character... like '\0' which is null?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "prepare a base (i.e `'//'`)".  The primary issue is that if you see `printf("/* %d\n", '/*');` there are no comments in that code.  But see some of the excruciating stuff in my answer that is comment...not that you'll ever really encounter it in good code; people do not split the comment start symbols (or comment end symbols) in real life.  But as a compiler writer, or general-purpose tool writer, you have to deal with those cases too — or document carefully that you don't.  That code doesn't show any trigraphs, but `??/` is a backslash.

Comment: Well, the book has only taught basic character sifting and sorting, so I guess there will be a part that covers these 'exceptions' ( since they shouldn't be too common :) )
for example, would
if(c == '//') // C is a char which will be given a value by getchar()

OR

if(c == '\')
    backlslash++;

else
backslash = 0;

if(backslash > 1)
   removecomm();

Comment: Ignore most of the torture test I supplied — you aren't ready for it.  You'll not read a value via `getchar()` etc that matches `'//'`.  The I/O functions deal in single characters and would return `'/'` followed by `'/'` as input from the file.  You won't be writing `'//'` in your analyzer; you'll be recognizing when you read one slash followed by another slash, and deleting that and anything up to the end of line.  If you're brave, you'll recognize backslash newline as 'not the end of comment' and gobble the next line too.  Similarly with `'/'` followed by `'*'`.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ The trick is to recognize when you start a character string (a `"` character) and to gobble that without looking for comments in it, remembering that `"..\".." "..\".."` is two strings, each containing a double quote, even though the C compiler ends up concatenating them.  And you need to recognize character literals too, recognizing that `'\000'` and `'\xABCD'` and `'\\'` and so on (including `'/*'` and `'//'` and `'*/'`) are all character constants.  Get that much working; then you can add bells and whistles later.